# How to upgrade to latest stable nginx on Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, nginx

I have a linode server  with  virtualmin that hosts several of my domains.
I am trying to find a guide on how to upgrade to latest stable nginx on Ubuntu 18 but the only article i found in medium said as a first step to Install the dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

BUT a get a message

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
sh: 1: $: not found
$ apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
sh: 1: $: not found
```

The rest of the guide sugest the following but i am not surewhat to do since the first step is not working

Add the repository for the stable version of Nginx

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
```

Now update it

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Run install

```
$ sudo apt-get install nginx
When it asks you if you want to keep using the old config or get the new config like this.
Configuration file '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** nginx.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
Select N(No). It will Install the new version of the current config files in /etc/nginx/sites-available directory.
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure where you are getting your instructions from but the first step you are failing at is not part of the official instructions posted at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/#stable_vs_mainline

```
$ sudo wget https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
$ sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
    deb https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
    deb-src https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
$ sudo apt-get remove nginx-common
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: also you can ref [Nginx Official Install](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#official-debian-ubuntu-packages)